# Find averages in an array of different numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I feel like I didn't phrase my title very well, can someone please correct it if you understand my question.

I have an array of

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,
       6,7,8,9,0,
       3,4,7,2,1,
       4,6,1,2,3,
       5,6,8,9,3
       2,3,4,5,6
      ]
```

And I want to do several things

1. Split it into chunks with the size of 5
2. Calculate the number of chunks. In this case, it should be 6 chunks.
3. Calculate the sum of numbers of all chunks in each position and divide it by the total number of chunks. In this case,

   `(1+6+3+4+5+2)/6, (2+7+4+6+6+3)/6, ..., (5+0+1+3+3+6)/6`
4. Return results as an array

   `var result = [3.5, 4.66, ..., 3]`

I have got the idea, but not sure how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: Why are you trying to average chunks like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code accomplishes what you want.

```
function averageValues (arr) {
    var chunks = Math.ceil(arr.length / 5); // find the number of chunks
    var sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // keep a running tally
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        sums[i % 5] += arr[i]; // add each element to the proper part of the sum
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < sums.length; i ++) {
        sums[i] /= chunks; // divide each part of the sum by the number of chunks
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by maintaining five separate sums to end with five separate averages.

Prepare your sums array of length 5:

```
var sums = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
```

For each number in your set, increment the corresponding sum by that number.

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)
  sums[x % 5] += arr[x];
```

Divide each sum by how many numbers were used:

```
var numbers = arr.length / 5; // 6 numbers each
var result = sums.map(
  function(s) {
    return s / numbers; // divide each sum by 6
  }
);
```

This uses the assumption that your set length is always a multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful:

```js
//The average method using an array

    function average(arr) {
         var sum = arr.reduce(function (a,b) { return a + b; },0)
         return sum/ arr.length
        }
    
//Chunk array method, it returns an array of the sliced arrays by size

    function chunkArray(arr, chunkSize){
        var numChunks = arr.length / chunkSize
        var chunks= []
        for (let index = 0; index < numChunks; index++) {
            chunks.push(arr.slice(index * chunkSize, (index * chunkSize) + chunkSize))   
        }
        return chunks
    }

//Finally, the average of arrays, it returns the average of each array
   
    function averageArrays(arrs){
        return arrs.map(function (arr) {
            return average(arr)
        })
    }

//Example of usage

    var chunks = chunkArray([
        1,2,3,4,5,
        6,7,8,9,0,
        3,4,7,2,1,
        4,6,1,2,3,
        5,6,8,9,3,
        2,3,4,5,6
       ],5)
    console.log(averageArrays(chunks))
```

Comment: I found some issues with the chunk generation, so I fixed the logic (currently waiting for peer review). However `averageArrays` still takes the average of a chunk, not the average of the number at index `i` in all chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more functional approach to your problem. This uses the assumption that your set length is always a multiple of 5.

```js
// add extra array helpers
Array.prototype.eachSlice = function (n, fn) {
  let slices = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i += n) {
    let slice = this.slice(i, i + n);
    slices.push(slice);
  }
  
  if (fn) slices.forEach(fn);
  
  return slices;
}

Array.prototype.sum = function (fn) {
  let fnReduce = fn ? (acc, ...args) => acc + fn(...args) : (acc, v) => acc + v;
  return this.reduce(fnReduce, 0);
}

Array.prototype.avg = function (fn) {
  return this.sum(fn) / this.length;
}

// actual solution
let arr = [
  1,2,3,4,5,
  6,7,8,9,0,
  3,4,7,2,1,
  4,6,1,2,3,
  5,6,8,9,3,
  2,3,4,5,6,
];

let chunkSize = 5;

console.log('--- question #1 ---');
console.log('Split it into chunks with the size of 5.');
console.log('-------------------');

let chunks = arr.eachSlice(chunkSize);
console.log(chunks);



console.log('--- question #2 ---');
console.log('Calculate the number of chunks. In this case, it should be 6 chunks.');
console.log('-------------------');

console.log(chunks.length);



console.log('--- question #3 ---');
console.log('Calculate the sum of numbers of all chunks in each position and divide it by the total number of chunks.');
console.log('-------------------');

let avgChunks = new Array(chunkSize).fill()
                .map((_, i) => chunks.avg(chunk => chunk[i]));
console.log('See the result under question #4.');



console.log('--- question #4 ---');
console.log('Return results as an array.');
console.log('-------------------');

console.log(avgChunks);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `chunks.avg(chunk => chunk[i])` only works as long as the last chunk is filled perfectly. If the last chunk is smaller you might want to call `chunks.map(chunk => chunk[i]).filter(n => typeof(n) !== 'undefined').avg()` instead if you don't want to count them towards the average, or `chunks.map(chunk => chunk[i]).avg(n => n ? n : 0)` if you want to count the missing values as `0`. (If `n` equals `0` it also jumps to the *else* statement but in this case it doesn't matter since it still returns `0`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think @Aplet123 has the most straight forward and easy to understand approach, though I changed up a little bit to suit my needs.

```
var chunks = Math.ceil(arr.length / 5) // Find the number of chunks
var sums = new Array(5).fill(0) // Keeps a running tally and fill values 0  
arr.map((x, i) => sums[i%5] += arr[i]) // add each element to the proper part of the sum
var avgs = sums.map((x) => x/chunks /divide each part of the sum by the number of chunks
```